# Reading YAML lists of objects in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, yaml

Assuming this YAML (saved in a file called `users.yml`):

```
- id: 1
  name: Unknown user
  reputation: 0

- id: 2
  name: Foo bar
  reputation: 4
```

and this Haskell `data` type:

```
data MyUser = MyUser {id :: Int,
                      name :: String,
                      reputation :: Int}
                      deriving (Show)
```

I want to use the [yaml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml) library to read the YAML into a `[MyUser]`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a `FromJSON` instance (note that this is called `FromJSON` as *yaml* is derived from the [*Aeson*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) library) as described in the [`Data.Yaml` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.5.3/docs/Data-Yaml.html).

A similar issue with Aeson was previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16547783/2597135) whereas the choice of a Haskell YAML library was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059806/reading-yaml-in-haskell)

Here's a minimal working example that converts the YAML file into a `[MyUser]`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Yaml
import Control.Applicative -- <$>, <*>
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

data MyUser = MyUser {id :: Int,
                      name :: String,
                      reputation :: Int}
                      deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON MyUser where
    parseJSON (Object v) = MyUser <$>
                           v .: "id" <*>
                           v .: "name" <*>
                           v .: "reputation"
    -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so fail.
    parseJSON _ = error "Can't parse MyUser from YAML/JSON"

main = do
         ymlData <- BS.readFile "users.yml"
         let users = Data.Yaml.decode ymlData :: Maybe [MyUser]
         -- Print it, just for show
         print $ fromJust users
```

Comment: I can't get this to work: `/app/Main.hs:21:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Yaml.Value’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: unordered-containers-0.2.8.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                       text-1.2.2.1:Data.Text.Internal.Text String
        Actual type: Yaml.Object
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘v’
      In the first argument of ‘(.:)’, namely ‘Transaction <$> v’
      In the first argument of ‘(.:)’, namely
        ‘(.:) Transaction <$> v "entryDate" <*> v’`

Comment: @adius I can't reproduce. `cabal sandbox init ; cabal install yaml ; cabal exec runghc index.hs` where `index.hs` is the code listed in the answer correctly produces `[MyUser {id = 1, name = "Unknown user", reputation = 0},MyUser {id = 2, name = "Foo bar", reputation = 4}]` for me. Maybe you can try `cabal update` and changing the package versions?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't import `.:` from `Data.Yaml`. I thought it was a function that was exported by `Control.Applicative`. Unfortunately the compiler error was not really helpful in that regard 