# Parsing several YAML documents in one file using Data.Yaml

Tags: haskell, yaml

Starting from the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292429/356440), I got something working quickly which parses a list of todo task items in a YAML file.

But if I ever add a second document, `Data.Yaml.decode` no longer decodes anything, and just returns `Nothing`.

Like this:

```
---
-   name: >
        this is a test task
    state: finished

-   name: >
        this is a second test task
    state: todo
---
-   name: noname
    state: nostate
```

I am wondering if it is possible at all to use the documents feature of YAML, when parsing with Data.Yaml?

Or I am doing something wrong?

This is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Yaml
import Control.Applicative -- <$>, <*>
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

data Task = Task {    name :: String,
                      state :: String }
                      deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Task where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Task <$>
                           v .: "name" <*>
                           v .: "state"
    -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so fail.
    parseJSON _ = error "Can't parse Task from YAML/JSON"

main = do
         ymlData <- BS.readFile "/tmp/test2.yaml"
         let users = Data.Yaml.decode ymlData :: Maybe [Task]
         -- Print it, just for show
         print $ fromJust users
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `...` to separate documents, like so:

```
---
-   name: >
        this is a test task
    state: finished

-   name: >
        this is a second test task
    state: todo
...
---
-   name: noname
    state: nostate
```

Comment: i'm going to try this.